# How to print statement that can then be manipulated for STDIN?

Tags: perl

I would like to prefill the STDIN with a string. This will allow the user to delete the string if they do not want it for input or press return and the prefilled statement will be accepted as STDIN.

How would I go about doing this in perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't be done by using the STDIN/STDOUT *file* handles. Instead, you'll have to interact with the terminal, e.g. using a `Term::Readline` module.

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Term::ReadLine::Perl5;

my $terminal = Term::ReadLine::Perl5->new("example");
my $result = $terminal->readline("> ", "default value");
say "you gave: $result";
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. How do I use `Term::ReadLine::Perl5` ? I can't install it with `cpan  Term::ReadLine::Perl5`.

Comment: @Senior-Jesticle Installing the module like that should work. I don't know why it failed for you.

Comment: I was able to install the package and your answer works as expected. Thanks! Branching off a little, how do I disable the bold and underline style of the readline prompt?

Comment: I don't know if the module provides such options. You can perhaps override formatting with [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), e.g. using the [Term::ANSIColor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) module.